# Переопределение JsonResponse

Tags: php, symfony

Необходимо реализовать следующий функционал:
При вызове `new JsonResponse($arg)` нужно проверять: если выполняется `is_method($arg->toArray())` то передавать в `$arg` результат выполнения `->toArray()`

Каким образом грамотней это реализовать?

ArgumentResolver проверяет сам аргумент, но мне не везде нужно передавать -`>toArray()` при его наличии у объекта.

Мне же необходимо реализовать преобразование аргумента **только** при вызове конструктора JsonResponse.

На данный момент реализован слушатель событий, который применяет encoding к объекту-экземпляру JsonResponse:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventListener;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;

/**
 * Class JsonResponseFormatterListener
 * @package App\EventListener
 */
class JsonResponseFormatterListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        if ($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }
}
```

Однако уже на этом моменте в Response находится результат выполнения `new JsonResponse($arg)`, а поскольку `$arg` - объект, то внутри `JsonResponse` содержится некорректная структура.
Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php